# Mutt not displaying HTML attachments in w3m after upgrade

Tags: mutt

(Note: This may be the same problem as [After upgrade to 18.04, Mutt shows raw html when opening html mails in chrome](https://askubuntu.com/q/1072769/25560), except the accepted solution there doesn't help me, as can be seen from one of the attempts below.)

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu server from Xenial (16.04) to Bionic (18.04).  Prior to the upgrade, viewing an HTML attachment in Mutt would cause an instance of w3m to be started for interactive reading of the HTML; however, after the upgrade, trying to view an HTML attachment instead causes Mutt to invoke w3m with `-dump` and display the resulting unstyled text in Mutt's internal pager.  How do I get the old behavior back?

Relevant settings and attempted fixes:

- `/etc/mailcap` currently contains the following lines in the given order for `text/html`:

  ```
  text/html; /usr/bin/sensible-browser %s; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
  text/html; /usr/bin/w3m -T text/html %s; needsterminal; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
  text/html; /usr/bin/w3m -I %{charset} -dump -T text/html %s; copiousoutput; description=HTML Text; nametemplate=%s.html
  ```
- My Mutt config contains the line `auto_view text/html message/rfc822 application/x-tar-gz`; removing `text/html` causes HTML attachments to be displayed as just the raw source
- I tried creating a `~/.mailcap` file with just the line `text/html; /usr/bin/w3m -T text/html %s; needsterminal; nametemplate=%s.html`, but Mutt still insists on using the `-dump` command for displaying HTML.

Comment: My own system works well with an empty `/etc/mailcap` (actually this file does not exist at all) and a user mailcap with only 2 relevant lines: `auto_view text/html` and `text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/html; copiousoutput;` and this works well enough on my system...

Comment: WHY w3m -I %{charset} ?? -I is the input charset, but the input IS html. We have to specify output charset imho